How to resolve the issues with puppeteer with nodejs 20 upgrade?
Recently, I tried to upgrade nodejs to 20 and angular: 15.2.10 and replaced phantomjs with puppeter: ^20.9.0 as part of using Headless Chrome. So locally I'm able to run it but when im trying to deploy over jules i'm getting this error.
Error: Could not find Chrome (ver. 115.0.5790.98). This can occur if either
1. you did not perform an installation before running the script (e.g. npm install)
2. your cache path is incorrectly configured

Note: I have tried couple of fixes to get away with this but i'm not able to fix it: node node_modules/puppeteer/install.js
downloaded exact version of chromedriver
tried cleaning node modules
PUPPETEER_SKIP_DOWNLOAD:
true

I haven't encountered these problems. Can you provide all commands, package.json, and code so I can reproduce this? What is Jules?

running, "npm i puppeteer" should install Chrome on the machine.  (error seems to indicate Chrome browser is not installed)  The version of Puppeteer you are running is pretty out of date, so it may be that your current Chrome browser install is much more recent than v115.xx
